Passing data from async Task<string> to another function, interface freezes
I try to pass data form async Task<string> to another function, but after I run code the interface is freezing I don't know why.
 private void Received_FromBarcode(object s, EventArgs e)
 {
     BarcodeBuff += BarcodeData;
     if (BarcodeBuff.Contains("\r"))
     {
         string[] Barcodesplit = BarcodeBuff.Split('\r');
         string[] tempbarcode = Barcodesplit[0].Split(',');
         //tbResult.Text = getdataFormMIS(tempbarcode[0], tempbarcode[1]).Result;
         tbResult.Text = getdataFormMIS(tempbarcode[0], tempbarcode[1]).Result;
         BarcodeBuff = "";
     }
 }

 public class MyData
 {
     public string PCBA_SN { get; set; }
     public string MODULE_ID { get; set; }

     public MyData()
     {
         PCBA_SN = "";
         MODULE_ID = "";
     }
 }

 static async Task<string> getdataFormMIS(string pcb,string module)
 {
     var data = new MyData { PCBA_SN = pcb, MODULE_ID = module };
     string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
     string tempdataresult = "";
     using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
     {
         var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

         var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://10.5.65.150:6245/check-core-id", content);
         
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             //return responseContent;
             tempdataresult= responseContent;
         }
         else
         {
             tempdataresult= $"HTTP request failed with status code {response.StatusCode}";
         }
     }

     return tempdataresult;
 }

I want to know how to use data in async Task<string> in another function.
I need to use responseContent in another function or call another function to do something.

When you use .Result the execution of your Received_FromBarcode is blocked. You need to make that function async as well and use await.

If you want to call an async method from an event handler, you should declare the event handler async as well and then await the async method. Generally speaking, you should not declare a method async void but event handlers are the exception.
private async void Received_FromBarcode(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    BarcodeBuff += BarcodeData;
    if (BarcodeBuff.Contains("\r"))
    {
        string[] Barcodesplit = BarcodeBuff.Split('\r');
        string[] tempbarcode = Barcodesplit[0].Split(',');
        //tbResult.Text = getdataFormMIS(tempbarcode[0], tempbarcode[1]).Result;
        tbResult.Text = await getdataFormMIS(tempbarcode[0], tempbarcode[1]);
        BarcodeBuff = "";
    }    
}

